# GRANT ALTER to role vs. GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-sql-server

Suppose you create a user defined database role as follows:

```
CREATE ROLE TestRole AUTHORIZATION dbo
```

**Question**: Which of the following two permissions are more restrictive? Or, do the both statements serve the same purpose (members of TestRole can alter any database objects)?

1. `GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: dbo To TestRole;`
2. `GRANT ALTER To TestRole;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first only grants the permissions on the dbo schema.
2. The second grants the permission on all schemas in the database.

I.e., the first is more restrictive.

Here's a repro:

```
USE Adventureworks
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.mytable, dbo.mytable2, Sales.mytable, Sales.mytable2
DROP USER IF EXISTS TestRole

CREATE USER TestRole WITHOUT LOGIN
GRANT CREATE TABLE to TestRole

GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: dbo To TestRole;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestRole'
--OK
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable(c1 int)
GO
--Fails
CREATE TABLE Sales.mytable(c1 int)
GO
REVERT
REVOKE ALTER ON SCHEMA :: dbo To TestRole;

GRANT ALTER To TestRole;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestRole'
--OK
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable2(c1 int)
GO
--OK
CREATE TABLE Sales.mytable2(c1 int)
GO
REVERT
```